# Extending more than one phpunit class

Tags: phpunit

I know that I can't extend two classes in php but I wonder, if I need to test a class with `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` but the class also interacts with a database using and so I need to use the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`.
Can I use both in the same test class or I need to have two separate ones?

This is part of the class I am trying to test:

```
    <?php
    use Slim\Slim;

    /**
     * All ad rules to match against
     */
    class AdRules {
      public $site;
      public $placement;
      protected $db = null;
      protected $filter = array();

      function __construct(){
      }


       /*some more methods*/

      function getRules() {
        $DBH = $this->getDbh();
        $where = $this->getWhereClause();
        if (!empty($where)) {
          $where = 'WHERE '.$where;
        }
        $query = "select * from rules {$where} order by site, placement, dof_count asc";
        try {
          $STH = $DBH->query($query);
          $rules = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'AdRule');
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
          Slim::getInstance()->log->error($e);
        }
        return $`enter code here`rules;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.

`abstract class PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` [see definition](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/7a8007cab7f1d6fcb9977550eeaf3cb180829fbb/src/Extensions/Database/TestCase.php)

Although, in fact all it add is a `use PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase_Trait;`
So you could just add that 'use' line and have your testclass extend the original TestCase as you would normally, and still have all the functionality of the Database_TestCase as well.